# Spring beans injection info jsp

Tags: spring, jsp, jstl, tiles

i have two jsp one header and one main page.
header is included into main page using jsp:include tag.

header is created as follows

```
<bean id="header" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView">
    <property name="url" value="/jsp/storePlaceTopNavigation.jsp" />
    <property name="exposeContextBeansAsAttributes" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

and

```
<bean id="mainpage" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView">
    <property name="url" value="/jsp/storePlaceTopNavigation.jsp" />
</bean>
```

problem is

```
${bo.someValue}
```

is not accessible in header untill  add this line

```
<property name="exposeContextBeansAsAttributes" value="true"/> to main page view.
```

my controller redirects to mainpageView (jstl view).
and i dont want to include that line into main page view as i have lots of jsp.

Comment: Apologies for being thick but what is the actual question? I understand the problem but not what the question is. Could you please edit and make the actual question more clear...

Comment: Question is simple, i want to inject beans on header view and use also in header view. which is included in main view. controller forwards to main view. and main view includes header view. property is not accessible in header view until i also inject beans in main view.